# How to turn off USB drive activity light on Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, usb, boot, external-hard-drive

I just loaded ubuntu 12.10 and after I have copied from the USB drive and I eject it the light on my USB drive or the External drive is still on(the blue activity light in USB drive).

I do not want the USB drive or the External drive to get corrupted.I want the lights to be switched off so that I can safely remove the USB drive or the external hard drive and it will not get corrupted.

I could do it in windows, but how do I do this in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

Simply, right click on USB drive and unmount or safely remove the drive. I hope this will work for you.

Comment: when i right click on the drive i select eject the blue light on the usb drive is still on , i want the usb drive to be switched off.

Comment: Can any body help me on this one?

Comment: @mahesh click on safely remove.